# What is a data structure to lookup an object based on an id and find the minimum value of an associated field for each object in the DS fast

Tags: algorithm, search, priority-queue

I have a set of objects that have the following fields:

```
id
time
```

I am looking for a data structure that can look up an object's `id` fast (about `O(log n)`). Also, I need to keep account of the object that has the smallest amount of time and removes this minimum object fast `O(log n)`. Additionally, an object's `time` field is mutable.

I thought about using a combination of a binary search tree and priority heap to do this. Essentially, the keys of the priority heap will be `time` and the values will be the object themselves. The keys of the binary search tree will be `id` and values will be the object itself along with a pointer to the entry representing the object in the heap. Is there a name for this type of data structure?

Comment: Your approach is good. AFAK, there is no name for such data structure.

Comment: A `Dictionary` in C# would do it. And you can query it using LINQ.

Comment: It does look a lot like an LRU cache.

Comment: I think "indexed priority queue" is the term you're looking for.